# How to Update an adapter except the progressbar?

Tags: android, adapter

I have a custom adapter to show some images in a gridview.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    private Context context;

    ArrayList<String> list = null;


    public CustomAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    l
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }


    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;

    }


    public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        String string= list.get(position);
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);

        ImageView iView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

        if (string != null) {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(string);
        } else {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.img_loading);
        }
        iView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        iView.setTag(position);

        return view;
    }


}
```

This is the adapter for a gridview.When selecting gridview items, it downloads a corresponding file and the progressbar makes visible. But when i am invoking notifyDatasetChanged() the progressbar retains its initial state.

How can i keep/show the state/progress of progressbar even if notifyDatasetChanged() is called?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the notifyDatasetChanged() - getView is invoked for all of visible items on the list. Your progress is destroyed because it's a new view. One optimization thing could be to use the convertView and check (by string value from list) if convertedView is the same as previous view. When you don't move the list in most cases convertView should be exactly the same view and you could make changes and return it. It will be the same progressBar so progress will not be lost.
To make it work properly in all cases you should remember the progress for all currently downloaded items for example (Hashmap of String, Integer so name->progress) and get current progress in getView method.

```
getView(...){
   String string= list.get(position);
   Integer progress = map.get(string);
   if (progress != null){
      final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
      progress.setProgress(progress);
   }
   ....
}
```

PS. In your code I see:

```
public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent)
```

second parameter in getView is not a "child" but a "convertView" - used for optimizing your list. The main idea is that you should inflate the view only when convertView is null, otherwise you should update it and use it. This is always a view which dissapears from the screen.

EDIT:
I forgot about 1 thing. I suppose durring the download you update the progressbar. Your downloader task keeps a reference to ProgressBar which he updates. You will need to give him your new progressBar or save the one that he is using (for example HashMap String -> ProgressBar instead of Integer) and use it somehow in your getView method. For example addChild... When you make sure that this is always the same instance of ProgressBar - everything will work fine :)